# Coding grid layout

Tags: html, css, html-table

I made a graphic header what I want to slice up and code. I have planned where to slice the image but am unsure how to go about coding it. [HERE is what the header looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV8rg.gif). I can see how I would code it using two tables side-by-side but am wondering how I would code it using DIVs or simply as one table (without adding extra cells). It's complicated for me since each cell is a different size and cell spans are irregular. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Will the cells all be a fixed pixel value forever (like in your picture) or will they need to scale up/down?

Comment: @Pat fixed forever

Comment: if you don't have to support anything lower than IE11, I would go for flexboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't need your boxes to scale, I would just go with a bunch of hard coded height/width divs. Here is an example of what I mean:

```css
.wrapper{
  font-size: 0;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.a{
  height: 34px;
  width: 154px;
}

.b, .c, .d{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 106px;
}

.b{
  width:42px;
}

.c{
  width: 88px;
}

.d{
  width: 24px;
}

.e{
  height: 60px;
}

.f{
  height: 107px;
  width:346px;
}

.g, .h, .i, .j, .k{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 46px;
}

.g{
  width: 54px;
}

.h{
  width: 38px;
}

.i{
  width: 124px;
}

.j{
  width: 86px;
}

.k{
  width:44px;
}

.l{
  height: 47px;
}


.wrapper div:nth-child(1){
  background: red;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(2){
  background: blue;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(3){
  background: green;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(4){
  background: yellow;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(5){
  background: purple;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(6){
  background: grey;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(7){
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="d"></div>
    <div class="e"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="f"></div>
  <div class="g"></div>
  <div class="h"></div>
  <div class="i"></div>
  <div class="j"></div>
  <div class="k"></div>
  <div class="l"></div>
</div>
```

And a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwGQKb)

Comment: Wow this is very helpful for learning. Thanks so much! Would you suggest using this method to code it? Or is there a better, more flexible coding you would use?

Comment: It really depends on what you need now, and in the future. If you strictly need fixed width/height boxes I would probably go with this approach. Others have suggested `flex box`, or `display: table` but both of those overly complicate things because they scale. Same goes for `display: grid`. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRzOXY is the example but using grid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `div` instead of `tables` here then you can use CSS `display:table` property, for eg:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="display:table">
    <div class="c1" style="display: table-cell; width:154px; height: 34px">
        <!-- Same way you can carry put your other block starting with display:table -->
    </div>
    <div class="c2" style="display: table-cell; width:346px; height:107px">
        <!-- Same way you can carry put your other block starting with display:table -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I have added the css property inline for demonstration purpose. Taking them out to a separate file should save some of your time!

Note: here table and table-cell property act as html table elements. Check out this [post for more on CSS display table property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/#display-table)